# Qgis2threejs layer disappear when tilting low

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs, three-js

I was able to create an interactive 3d model with the help of the splendid QGIS, Qgis2threejs-plugin and open Geodata (DEM, DSM, Orthophoto and Buildings all come from public sources but are downloaded (no WMS-layers).

When I tilt the model too much, the baselayer suddenly disappears, as visible in the two screenshot below. There seems to be a certain angle, below which this layer just doesn't render anymore. This angle depends on the zoom level. The closer I zoom in, the higher the angle needs to be. Any reason why this is so and what I can do against it?

I tried with various settings and resolutions. It seemed the higher the resolution, the worse the behavior. Clipping the DEM did not help either.

Chrome doesn't list any errors in the console, so I'm a bit lost here.

[image: all fine]
[image: baselayer lost]

Comment: Is the error still happening at the linked URL for you?

Comment: no, this link currently contains the version with activated "Enable the Viewer to Run Locally".

Comment: Ah, ok, Please add that info to the question or remove the link. I was very confused when I tried to help. :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, a workaround was to activate "Enable the Viewer to Run Locally" and uploading that version to my server.